# What would be the best way to transmit data from one python script to another, without them being on the same computer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to create a basic chatroom in python, and I would like to know how I could transmit data from one script to another, preferably without using google drive. If needed to, I could create a webserver on Replit, but I don't do well with HTML or PHP.

Side note: I can't port forward, as my google wifi doesn't accept any level of port forwarding.

I would send messages of about 50 characters every couple seconds

Comment: This question can have many answers. One such answer is a message passing broker such as this rabbitmq tutorial https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html.

Comment: You normally want a server receiving and delivering messages.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it

Comment: Maybe this will also be helpful ? https://github.com/anirbanroydas/rabbitChat.

Comment: This question is quite unspecific, but I would recommend using the builtin python module 'socket'. With it, you can send packets of information, such as strings, within a network. There are many tutorials for this on YouTube. e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3UOyky9sEQY

Comment: You'd need to be clearer about what you want to transmit, how big it is, how often, and how the two scripts are related. Are they on the same machine? In the same room? On the same network?

Comment: Bluetooth fits the question as written. As does a serial cable.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention port forwarding, I assume you want two chat clients that run on different local networks to talk to each other, for example your own and the chat client of a friend in a remote location, over the internet.

If you (or your counterpart) cannot set up port forwarding, then direct communication between the script on your computer and theirs is hard, if not impossible. The solution is to set up a third computer or service on the internet that can be reached by both clients and use it for relaying messages between them.

A network is typically protected by a firewall of sorts and will typically be behind a router that performs network address translation (NAT) to help multiple devices on a network to simultaneously access services on the internet, whilst all using the same IP address on the internet. Port forwarding fits into that by connecting a specific port from the outside directly to a port on a machine on the inside - without that, an outside computer might be able to reach your IP address, but they could never connect to a computer or program on the inside of the network, as the router wouldn't know what computer to contact, also the firewall might disallow the connection to begin with.

But if your computer on the inside establishes a connection with an accessible server on the internet, expecting a response, that creates a temporary conduit through the router and firewall that can be used by the server to send messages (look up 'hole punching' for more information). And if both computers do this, the server can relay message between both clients. Only the server then needs to run in an environment that doesn't have firewall restrictions or NAT that prevent this.

You could write a simple Python server, that accepts incoming connections and can send several responses and a simple client that connects to it, identifying itself and joining a chatroom, or having a direct conversation with another connected client. There are many techniques that would allow you to do this, but I think web sockets might be a good starting point, as long as you don't plan to do advanced fast or high volume stuff that would require something like a UDP connection.

A library like [websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) could be a good starting point, but you may want to start out by figuring out where you would have this service hosted first, since there may be limitations on what you're able and allowed to do.

Also, if all you're looking to do is send simple messages, you may want to stay away from writing your own server an protocols at all - have a look around for open source message servers written in a language you are comfortable with, or that just work out of the box without any development, in which case the language doesn't even really matter, as long as you can connect to it and exchange messages from Python.